# Qt/Ruby Application Crash in Qt::AbstractItemModel::mimeData - How to find and fix the cause?

Tags: ruby, qt, crash, qtruby

Recently I wrote a little application using Ruby and Qt. It was my first non-trivial project with qtruby. After some time I managed to translate C++ references and tutorials into working Ruby code, and got the hang of it.

Only when implementing my own drag and drop functionality in  `QTreeView` widgets, I got really stuck. I could isolate the problem to the `Qt::AbstractItemModel::mimeData` method. After eliminating some other mistakes, I ended up with the following code which somehow caused the application to **crash** as soon as a drag action occured.

```
class TreeModel < Qt::AbstractItemModel
  def mimeData(indexlist)
    encodedData = Qt::ByteArray.new("")
    stream = Qt::DataStream.new(encodedData, Qt::IODevice::WriteOnly)  

    indexlist.each do |index|
      if index.column == 0
        if index.isValid
          stream << index.item.mime_data.to_json
        end
      end
    end

    mimeData = Qt::MimeData.new
    mimeData.setData("application/x-tegi.json", encodedData)
    mimeData
  end
end
```

The crash appeared non-deterministic, a few times the code just worked. The error dump and backtrace did not give me a hint, only that the crash happened inside `QApplication::exec`.

**What is the issue and how can it be fixed?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ prototype for `mimeData` is :

```
QMimeData * QAbstractItemModel::mimeData 
  ( const QModelIndexList & indexes ) const [virtual]
```

The method returns a pointer to a `QMimeData` object. My implementation of `mimeData` was **returning a pointer to a local variable**. Thus the non-deterministic crashes.

Once found, fixing the issue was easy. An instance variable would stay alive and keep its value until the next call of `mimeData`:

```
  @mimeData = Qt::MimeData.new
  @mimeData.setData("application/x-tegi.json", encodedData)
  @mimeData
end
```

Another possibility is to call `super` and leave the construction and deconstruction to the superclass. This also inherits the default mime data ("application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist"):

```
  mimeData = super
  mimeData.setData("application/x-tegi.json", encodedData)
  mimeData
end
```

After having found the issue, it appears trivial to me. Nevertheless I would like to share it, because I wasted too much time with it. The qtruby documentation warns about pointer arguments and mentions some unsupported functions returning `uchar` pointers, but no word about functions returning pointers to Qt objects. Being lulled by qtruby seamlessly wrapping data types to and fro, I looked so many times over that little asterisk without spotting it.